CANNOT override Service in NestJS/Vitest
We are implementing e2e testing in an application using NestJS/Vitest/Prisma.
I used overrideProvider to Mock ItemsService in my ItemsController test, but it doesn't work.
The test code and test results are shown below.
The authentication and authorization are implemented with reference to the following official site.
JwtAuthGuard is globally enabled in AppModule.
https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/passport
I am using overrideProvider(ItemsService) and useValue(itemsServiceMock), but it seems that the ItemsService function is being executed instead of itemsServiceMock.
I expect the overrideProvider and useValue to work and return items as a response to GET /items.
I would appreciate it if you could let me know if there are any mistakes.

Test results:
stdout | test/items.e2e-spec.ts > ItemsController (e2e) > 200 /items (GET)
ItemsController Called
CANNOT override service! Original service is used!

 ❯ test/items.e2e-spec.ts (2)
   ❯ ItemsController (e2e) (2)
     × 200 /items (GET)
     ✓ 401 /items (GET)

FAIL  test/items.e2e-spec.ts > ItemsController (e2e) > 200 /items (GET)
Error: expected [
  ItemDto {
    id: 1,
    body: 'test',
    status: 'TODO',
    userId: 1,
    createdAt: 2024-06-09T09:43:14.038Z,
    updatedAt: 2024-06-09T09:43:14.038Z
  },
  ItemDto {
    id: 2,
    body: 'test',
    status: 'TODO',
    userId: 1,
    createdAt: 2024-06-09T09:43:14.038Z,
    updatedAt: 2024-06-09T09:43:14.038Z
  }
] response body, got {}

package.json(Excerpt):
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.2.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.3",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.15.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.9.2",
    "passport": "^0.7.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "prisma": "^5.15.0",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "vitest": "^1.6.0",
    "vitest-mock-extended": "^1.3.1"
  }

items.e2e-spec.ts:
const date = new Date();
const items = [
  new ItemDto(1, 'test', Status.TODO, 1, date, date),
  new ItemDto(2, 'test', Status.TODO, 1, date, date),
];

describe('ItemsController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let jwtService: JwtService;
  let configService: ConfigService;
  let prismaServiceMock: DeepMockProxy<PrismaService>;
  let itemsServiceMock: DeepMockProxy<ItemsService>;

  const getToken = (payload: object) => {
    return jwtService.sign(payload, {
      secret: configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
    });
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    prismaServiceMock = mockDeep<PrismaService>();
    itemsServiceMock = mockDeep<ItemsService>();

    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    })
      // CANNOT override!!! NOT working.
      .overrideProvider(ItemsService)
      .useValue(itemsServiceMock)
      // Working!
      .overrideProvider(PrismaService)
      .useValue(prismaServiceMock)
      .compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    //app.useLogger(new Logger());
    configService = moduleFixture.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);
    jwtService = moduleFixture.get<JwtService>(JwtService);

    await app.init();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  it('200 /items (GET)', async () => {
    const token = getToken({ sub: 1, username: 'test' });

    const expected = items;
    itemsServiceMock.findAll.calledWith(any()).mockResolvedValue(expected);

    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/items')
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      .expect(200)
      .expect(expected);
  });

  it('401 /items (GET)', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/items').expect(401);
  });
});

app.module.ts:
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    ItemsModule,
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: JwtAuthGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

items.module.ts:
@Module({
  providers: [ItemsService, PrismaService],
  controllers: [ItemsController],
})
export class ItemsModule {}

items.controller.ts:
@Controller('items')
export class ItemsController {
  constructor(private readonly itemsService: ItemsService) {}

  @Get()
  async findAll(@Request() req): Promise<ItemDto[]> {
    console.log('ItemsController Called');
    return await this.itemsService.findAll({ userId: req.user.id });
  }
}

items.service.ts:
@Injectable()
export class ItemsService {
  constructor(private readonly prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async findAll(itemWhereInput: Prisma.ItemWhereInput): Promise<ItemDto[]> {
    console.log('CANNOT override service! Original service is used!');
    return toDtoArray(
      ItemDto,
      await this.prisma.item.findMany({ where: itemWhereInput }),
    );
  }
}


My guess is that the ItemsService override is not compiled (i.e .compile()).
I'm not sure if it's possible to chain multiple overrides, haven't tried that before.
But here's perhaps a more elegant way to override multiple services:
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ItemsService,
          useValue: itemsServiceMock
        },
        {
          provide: PrismaService,
          useValue: prismaServiceMock
        }
      ]
    })


Thanks for your response.
I tried to implement it as suggested, but unfortunately it was not overridden.
However, the result was a little different, from {} to [].
